# PHP warning on Guzzle failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, error

We just deployed Craft to Elastic Beanstalk running on a docker container. 
When we revisit the site hours later at random it gives us a warning:

PHP warning

include(/var/www/craft/app/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Refreshing helps and load the application properly.
Has anybody stumbled with this and so yes would be great if you have some tips!

Thanks

Comment: Does the file exist on the file system?  Sounds like maybe some files didn't get deployed properly.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for taking a look, the wrong app branch was deployed to AWS which did not have to folder. Fixed now!

Comment: Mind adding that as an official answer?

Answer (score 2):

Files were not added to the deployment branch!